# Jquery modifying the click function of a button .

Tags: jquery

I am trying o learn jQUERY , i am trying with different types of things in jquery .
I got this query , on click of a button , i am using the click funcion of a button to call another function , as shown .

But this isn't working .

Could you please tell me , cant we use the click this way

```
$("button").click() instead of standard  $("button").click(function(){
```

=====

This is my code

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js" >
 </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click()
{
   callMe();

}
});

function callMe()
{
 $("p").hide();
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h2>This is a heading</h2>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<button>Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can I know why you want to use it that way. function() inside the click is called a callback. So, it is like the return value after your operation is done. You can use the code below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery is a library built for the JavaScript language, not an actual language itself, and is thus restricted to what JavaScript lets it do.

```
$("button").click()
{
   callMe();
}
```

So why the above won't work is because `.click()` is a method in jQuery that takes in arguments/parameters, not an actual part of the JavaScript language itself, which doesn't let you use a block in that way.

```
$("button").click(function()
{
   callMe();
});
```

The function itself is an argument/parameter being passed to the `click` method. See if you can understand what's going on this way:

```
var myFunction = function()
{
   callMe();
};
$("button").click(myFunction);
```

Or this way:

```
function myFunction()
{
   callMe();
}
$("button").click(myFunction);
```

The above three code blocks would all cause `callMe()` to be called when anything matching `button` is clicked.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot , you have spend enough time for presenting the answer in a good manner , thanks once again .

Answer (score 1):

```
function callMe()
{
 $("p").hide();
}


$(function(){
  $("button").click(callMe)// just provide the reference to call me
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZZt7R/)